# Pagination works improper and creates error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am making a Django Project, a Business Directory. Here I used the Pagination in the HTML page. But I am getting an error which says:

> KeyError at /crawlerapp/search/"
>   I am following the procedure as given on the link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pagination/1.0.5.

The HTML code where I am using pagination is:

```
{% load pagination_tags %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block head_title %}SearchPage{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{% block title %}The Blue Day, A Search Directory by Abhimanyu Choithramani{% endblock %}</h1>
    {% block content %}
    <div style="text-transform: uppercase;" id="network-bar">
      <dl>
        <dd>*          <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/crawlerapp/">Homepage</a>    

                *          <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/crawlerapp/contactus">Contact Us</a></dd>
      </dl>
    <dl>
      <dd class="last" style="float: right;"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/crawlerapp/" title="Blue Day Business Directory">Blue Day Business Directory</a></dd>
    </dl>
    <div class="network-bar-search"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="border-top: 1px dashed #6b88a5; margin: 10px;"></div>
  <div style="padding: 0 10px 10px; position: relative;">
    Search our <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/crawlerapp/">Business Directory</a> by entering a business type or name and just click on a Search.
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative;" id="headerSearchindex">
    <form action='' method="GET">
      <table style="width: 60%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td class="hsTableTitleCell leftSpaced"> By category: </td>
          <td class="hsTableTitleCell leftSpaced">Or by company name:</td>
          <td style="width: 300px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="hsTableBusinessCell leftSpaced"><input type="text" title="Business Category" placeholder="e.g Computer, Restaurants" name="what"  autocomplete="off" value=""/></td>
          <td class="hsTableCompanyCell leftSpaced"><input type="text" title="Company Name" placeholder="e.g Smith and Sons" name="who" value=""/></td>
          <td class="hsTableSearchButtCell leftSpaced"><input name="search_action" type="submit" value="Search"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  {% autopaginate crawlerapp %}
  <p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>
  {% if crawlerapp %}
  <p>Found {{ crawlerapp|length }} in this Category{{ crawlerapp|pluralize }}.</p>
  <ul>
    {% for Directory in crawlerapp %}
    <li>Business Name:  {{ Directory.Bussiness_name }}</li>
    Description: {{ Directory.Description }}</br>
    Contact Number: {{ Directory.Number }}</br>
    Web_URL:        {{ Directory.Web_url }}</br>
    Address:       {% for Adress in Directory.adress_set.all %}{{forloop.counter}}:-      {{ Adress.adress_name }}</br>{% endfor %}
    Photo:          {% for Photos in Directory.photos_set.all %}{{ Photos.Photo_name }}</br>{% endfor %}</br></br>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% else %}
    <p>No Business matched your search criteria.</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% paginate %}
</body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="footer"> &copy; Abhimanyu Choithramani's <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/crawlerapp/" >The Blue Day</a> is a Business Search Directory.</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Am I using the variable name correctly for pagination?
If yes where is the problem then?

Please help me.

Comment: The error is in your code, not your template, and it will tell you what line is causing the error. Please provide the error and the code.

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm, it's hard to tell where went wrong without the traceback specially when we don't know what key is missing. Do you get a debug page? That might help us figure out.

Also, just out of curiosity. Why do you choose this third-party pagination package over the Django built-in pagination https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/pagination/?

Comment: I tried this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/pagination/
but it was not working and so I used the other one,